# Spotify and google sheets crashing on ubuntu 16.04 asking for shockwave plugin

Tags: 16.04, firefox, flash, chromium

Suddenly my browsers asking for shockwave player plugin. This is happening in both Firefox and Chromium I get the error message `A plugin shockwave flash is not responding` As far as I understand shockwave is obsolete for Linux? I tried to follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Shockwave) on Ubuntu community wiki but I still get the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't ask for the *player*, but for a flash *plugin*. Flash as a technique is kind of obsolete (about to be replaced by HTML 5), but some web sites still rely on it.

Try this:

- Enable [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner).
- Install the `adobe-flashplugin` package.
- Restart the browser(s).

Comment: As far as the people still continue using such BAD and obsolete plugins the content providers will not patch their sites.